# How to prevent an Abstract Property Attribute Error?

Tags: python

Running into a problem where I am getting an attribute error from an abstract class.

I am trying to use subclass this in my concrete implementation and I am getting an error that stems from this abstract file.

The code below results in this.

`File "<frozen abc>", line 24, in abstractmethod` which is the line for my class and `AttributeError: attribute '__isabstractmethod__' of 'property' objects is not writable`

```
import abc

class MyClass(abc.ABC):

    @property
    @abc.abstractmethod
    def current_light(self) -> str:
        """
        Current light setting.
        """
        return ''

    @abc.abstractmethod
    @current_light.setter
    def current_light(self, value: str) -> None:
        """
        Set the current lighting.
        """
        pass
```

I tried to run the main file for this application but this error pops up. I rearranged the property and abstract method as I saw that in another post and that actually fixed an identical error a few lines above but it happened a few lines down again.

Comment: "I rearranged the property and abstract method as I saw that in another post and that actually fixed an identical error a few lines above but it happened a few lines down again." - because you made the *same mistake* a few lines down from the part you fixed, and you need to fix it there too.

Comment: What are the first two functions for? You never use them.

Comment: @Barmar I use them but mistakenly include them in my snippet. They are helpers for another method. Just removed them, apologies

Comment: Be sure you understand [how `abstractmethod` interacts with a `property`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/abc.html#abc.abstractproperty) in the first place.   (Components of) properties are abstract when getters and setters are abstract.

Comment: @user2357112 What I was trying to say is that I have fixed it there too. The difference about the one I fixed and the issue I am currently facing is that the other one wasn't a setter. I appears to only affect the setter properties

Comment: To prevent the error you have to put `@current_light.setter` before `@abc.abstractmethod`.

Comment: However, in my testing, making a setter abstract doesn't require that the subclass implement the setter.

Comment: @Barmar That was the fix, thank you!

Comment: @chepner Thanks for linking to the docs. The fix was in there, will read it further if I encounter any issues

Comment: @Mordi That's exactly what the first comment was talking about: You needed to make the same decorator ordering fix for the setter as the getter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/abc.html#abc.abstractmethod):

> When `abstractmethod()` is applied in combination with other method
> descriptors, it should be applied as the innermost decorator, as shown
> in the following usage examples...

Thus, `@abc.abstractmethod` should be the innermost, with other decorators such as `@property` or `@property.setter` above it.